# Automatically mount sshfs on login, using gnome keyring

Tags: linux, ssh, gnome, sshfs, gnome-keyring

I understand the purpose of `/etc/fstab` is used to mount volumes on boot. However, in my case I have an sshfs that requires an encrypted identity file.

So how would I go about supplying passphrase for the identity file when automatically mounting sshfs?

Obviously I don't want the passphrase or decrypted identity file out in the open. But I hate typing in my passwords over and over again. So my goal is to **have the sshfs connection mounted with the identity file which has been decrypted by the gnome keyring when I log into my computer**... what a mouthful.

Thanks!